# Dynamically make div fill remaining space based on sibling height

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to dynamically make a `div` fill remaining space in the window based on sibling height.

The idea is that if the `header` div changes height the `page-wrapper` will dynamically  change its height based on the remaining space. (avoid overflow if the `header` div changes height)

**Header.sass**

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="header">
        <div>
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="page-wrapper">
        div will fill remaining space
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Current solution**

i understand i can achieve this using `cal()` however this will involve changing the hard coded value for `$headerHeight` if the `header` height changes

```
.page-wrapper {
   height: calc(100vh - #{$headerHeight});
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this did answer my question, i cam across it earlier, but it didn't seem to work. I have just re tried it as per your suggestion and it now works (worry for the duplicate i'm tired today) Thank you